# Display an icon if a user has posted something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to show an icon with the names of users if they have posted something. I want to do this in the index action. Is there a way to access microposts of a user from index?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User Controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
  @user  = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.microposts
end
```

Comment: I would recommend setting up a counter cache for "microposts_count" in the User model. That way you don't need to query the DB so many times. And you if don't do that, at least eager load them. User.includes(:microposts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index` view:

```
<div id="users">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div id="user-<%= user.id %>">
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= image_tag user.image if user.microposts %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Be wary of the number of queries with this approach.

Comment: And what to do if I have to get content of a micropost like this user.microposts.content?

Comment: @FarhanHaider `microposts` it's a collection, nil? it's the same as empty?. ROWCOUNT == 0

Answer (score 1):

As @DaveNewton pointed out, with the approach posted/accepted, you can have an unlimited number of DB hits. I would recommend setting up a counter_cache.

```
# migration
def up
  add_column :users, :microposts_count, :integer

  User.includes(:microposts).find_each do |user|
    user.update_column(:microposts_count, user.microposts.size)
  end

def down
  remove_column :users, :microposts_count
end

# micropost.rb
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true

# index.html
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div id="user-<%= user.id %>">
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= image_tag user.image if user.microposts_count > 0 %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

> While the already accepted answer *does* achieve the desired result, for large applications where performance is key, I would not recommend it.